# Why my script execute in / instead of /mydir?

Tags: bash, shell-script

This is my script,it simply update 
a localrepo of slackware when notify a change
on fs.
It work in background,but has a little problem
instead of working in /userdir where are present
.gpg,it works in / and create a new .gnupg dir :/
and of course don't work.
My question is: how to force the script to work
on userdir and read gpg-agent and .gnupg keyrings
of useerdir?
I have tried cd  and (cd /usrdir) but none works
Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh
funct()
{
(cd /userdir)         #don't work :(
echo password|/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#script update repo http

/usr/local/bin/gen_repos_files.sh -l /tmp/emptylog -v

#find /var/localrepo -type f |xargs chmod 644  -v

}

while inotifywait -o /dev/null -qqre modify /var/localrepo; do funct; done
```

~
~

Comment: haw are you starting the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`( cmd )` executes `cmd` in a subshell. I.e. `cmd` cannot affect the environment of the main shell. Run

```
cd /userdir
```

instead. But the current working directory doesn't affect the usage of `gpg` because it expects its configuration directory to be `~/.gnupg`.

Your `~` seems to be set to `/` which is rather strange. You can either set `HOME` at the beginning of the script

```
export HOME="/userdir"
```

or set the directory for `gpg` only:

```
export GNUPGHOME="/userdir"
```

Comment: I try now,forgot subshell ()

Comment: Nope,it doesn't work

Comment: @elbarna I didn't pay enough attention: `(cd /userdir)` doesn't make sense but this error is not related to the problem. I have added the explanation for that.

Comment: Works fine now,added +

Comment: @elbarna If this solves your problem then you should accept the answer so that the other readers can see that this question is done.

Comment: @elbarna See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and for a screenshot http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Perfect,I did it

Answer (score 0):

This is my final script gpg-agent neeed to specify home (--homedir option)

```
#!/bin/sh
export HOME="/userdir"
export GNUPGHOME="/userdir/.gnupg"

funct()
{
pkill gpg-agent
rm ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
mknod -m 700 ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent p
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --allow-preset-passphrase --homedir="$(pwd)")
echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
echo XXX|/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#script update repo http

/usr/local/bin/gen_repos_files.sh -l /tmp/emptylog -v

find /var/repo/ -type f |xargs chmod 644  -v

}
cd /userdir
while inotifywait -o /dev/null -qqre modify /var/repo; do cd /userdir && funct; done
```

Comment: The environment variable `GNUPGHOME` works for `gpg-agent`, too. But it must be restarted for this to take effect. Creating `~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent` as a FIFO seems very strange to me. Even more as `gpg-agent` will not use it unless configured accordingly. Use the option `--use-standard-socket` for that. `gpg-agent` will create that **socket** (not a FIFO) then. There is also no use for `RELOADAGENT` if you have just started it. And there is no need for `rm ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent` either (unless it's your FIFO...).